# MVC - How to change 2nd div height by clicking on the 1st div?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to MVC and I want to achieve that if someone clicks on the 1st div, then the 2nd div height changes from 100px to 200px.

I know this can be done using JavaScript but I simply hate JavaScript. I would be grateful if could suggest any alternative way. It doesn't have to be achieved only using MVC, any other way would be useful.

Thank you in advance :)

**CSHTML :**

```
<div id="div1">DIV 1</div>

<div id="div2">DIV 2</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
#div1 {
    background-color: #FF0000;
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

#div2 {
    background-color: #FF0000;
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Razor/MVC is all "server side" - meaning once that page is sent to the client (browser) - MVC cannot alter the mark up.  The only way to do this without JS would be to request another page URL

Comment: @Tommy But it's not helpful for me...

Comment: I don't know what you mean "not helpful".  What you are asking for cannot be done with strictly MVC unless you issue another page request (ie, go to another URL)

Comment: Any reason you don't want to do this in javascript, other than you hate javascript?

Comment: @Tommy Tell me one thing then if I pass a http request or Url.Query like `/?div1` will affect the SEO or not?

Comment: @ssilas777 I'm worried if JavaScript is disabled by user..

Comment: I'm also not asking for doing this by only MVC, any other way will be useful. Thank you!

Comment: Check this out http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/23535/how-important-is-graceful-degradation-of-javascript

Comment: @LALITSHARMA - I have no idea, sorry, I am not a SEO expert.  But, that is how you would pass a new request to the server and respond with a view that has the div 1 being shorter!

Comment: @LALITSHARMA, I dont know why you hate javaScript, if you are a web developer then you are making a strange statement. what you want is a pure job of javaScript. you can pass values as querystring, it may NOT hurt your SEO, but you will be doing it the wrong way. Every website requires javaScript these days (pretty much), if javascript is disabled then give your users a message.

Comment: Thank you for all this conversation. What I'm trying to do is not like I want to increase the height of a div by clicking on else div in anywhere in my site. I can't come up with any other simple way to explain this. Think about it, if I can do this (by any chance) then I can avoid using JavaScript in my website. Sorry if I've done something wrong. :)

Comment: you need javascript to do client side changes.  even if you went down the crazy road of making div one a href to /home/biggerdiv then this would still serve no value, you may aswell just have the larger div.  you cant have your cake and eat it, you want animation, its client side, you want expanding content, its client side, its really that simple, change your plan, your idea does not work, if you dont want javascript thats cool, but dnt expect to have client side features